# How Event stream Works in wso2cep3.0.0

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, wso2-esb

I am working with wso2cep3.0.0,
My input source and out put source is JMs.I written my Input event adapter and output event adapter like this

> Input adapter

is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inputEventAdaptor name="jmsProxy" statistics="disable" trace="enable"
  type="jms" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventadaptormanager">
  <property name="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://localhost:61616</property>
  <property name="transport.jms.SubscriptionDurable">false</property>
  <property name="transport.jms.UserName">admin</property>
  <property name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</property>
  <property name="transport.jms.Password">admin</property>
  <property name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName">QueueConnectionFactory</property>
  <property name="transport.jms.DestinationType">queue</property>
</inputEventAdaptor>
```

and my

> Output event adapter

is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<outputEventAdaptor name="OUTJmsProxy" statistics="disable" trace="disable"
  type="jms" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventadaptormanager">
  <property name="java.naming.security.principal">admin</property>
  <property name="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://localhost:61616</property>
  <property name="java.naming.security.credentials">admin</property>
  <property name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</property>
  <property name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName">QueueConnectionFactory</property>
  <property name="transport.jms.DestinationType">queue</property>
</outputEventAdaptor>
```

and my input message in jmsproxy jms queue is like this

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <uuid>cc253480-95b3-418e-b282-7e87f885c99e</uuid>
   <Remarks>t4</Remarks>
   <ReadingsLiteTaildtos>
      <ReadingsLiteTaildto>
         <FinalValue>70</FinalValue>
         <InputText>Chiller Feeder Current R - Ph</InputText>
         <InputValue>0.0</InputValue>
         <ParameterId>-2499999974</ParameterId>
         <SlNo>1</SlNo>
      </ReadingsLiteTaildto>
      <ReadingsLiteTaildto>
         <FinalValue>70</FinalValue>
         <InputText>Chiller Feeder Current Y - Ph</InputText>
         <InputValue>0.0</InputValue>
         <ParameterId>-2499999973</ParameterId>
         <SlNo>2</SlNo>
      </ReadingsLiteTaildto>
      <ReadingsLiteTaildto>
         <FinalValue>70</FinalValue>
         <InputText>Chiller Feeder Current B - Ph</InputText>
         <InputValue>0.0</InputValue>
         <ParameterId>-2499999972</ParameterId>
         <SlNo>3</SlNo>
      </ReadingsLiteTaildto>
      <ReadingsLiteTaildto>
         <FinalValue>70</FinalValue>
         <InputText>Chiller Energy Meter Reading</InputText>
         <InputValue>0.0</InputValue>
         <ParameterId>-2499999971</ParameterId>
         <SlNo>4</SlNo>
      </ReadingsLiteTaildto>
   </ReadingsLiteTaildtos>
   <ReadingDateTime>1381757157596</ReadingDateTime>
   <PartyBranchId>-2500000000</PartyBranchId>
   <ParametersetId>-2499999974</ParametersetId>
   <AssetId>-2499999995</AssetId>
   <TaskId>811291126760647</TaskId>
   <WorkOUId>-1</WorkOUId>
   <activityid>-2500000000</activityid>
   <userid>-2499999993</userid>
   <entrymode>0</entrymode>
   <DeviceId>-1</DeviceId>
</soapenv:Body>
```

i wish to raise an event when final value cross the max value like more than 100
so how would i write Stream and

> ExecutionPlan

In stream-manger-config.xml file consist
3 section

> 1.metaData 2.Correlation Data 3.Payload Data

so above message how would i define which data is under which section
one more we should define input payload and out payload as well in same stream config file else we need to define separate

> Is cep help for this usecase or not

Thanx in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a typical usecase for CEP.

You can use an 'event builder' similar to following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eventBuilder name="ReadingsDtoBuilder" statistics="disable"
    trace="disable" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventbuilder">
<from eventAdaptorName="jmsEventReceiver" eventAdaptorType="jms">
    <property name="transport.jms.Destination">ReadingsQueue</property>
</from>
<mapping customMapping="disable"
    parentXpath="//ReadingsLiteTaildtos" type="xml">
    <property>
        <from xpath="//ReadingsLiteTaildto/ParameterId"/>
        <to name="meta_parameterId" type="string"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from xpath="//ReadingsLiteTaildto/Slno"/>
        <to name="meta_slno" type="string"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from xpath="//ReadingsLiteTaildto/FinalValue"/>
        <to name="finalValue" type="int"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from xpath="//ReadingsLiteTaildto/InputText"/>
        <to name="inputText" type="string"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from xpath="//ReadingsLiteTaildto/InputValue"/>
        <to name="inputValue" type="double"/>
    </property>
</mapping>
<to streamName="org.sample.readings.dto.stream" version="1.0.0"/>
</eventBuilder>
```

The execution plan can be as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<executionPlan name="ReadingsAnalyzer" statistics="disable"
  trace="disable" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventprocessor">
  <description>This execution plan analyzes readings and triggers notifications based on     threshold.</description>
  <siddhiConfiguration>
    <property name="siddhi.enable.distributed.processing">false</property>
    <property name="siddhi.persistence.snapshot.time.interval.minutes">0</property>
  </siddhiConfiguration>
  <importedStreams>
    <stream as="readings" name="org.sample.readings.dto.stream" version="1.0.0"/>
  </importedStreams>
  <queryExpressions><![CDATA[from readings[finalValue > 100]
select *
insert into notificationStream;]]></queryExpressions>
  <exportedStreams>
    <stream name="notificationStream" valueOf="notificationStream" version="1.0.0"/>
  </exportedStreams>
</executionPlan>
```

You can define streams inside stream-manager-config.xml similar to the following.

```
<streamDefinition name="org.sample.readings.dto.stream" version="1.0.0">
<metaData>
        <property name="parameterId" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="slno" type="STRING"/>
</metaData>
    <payloadData>
        <property name="finalValue" type="INT"/>
        <property name="inputText" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="inputValue" type="DOUBLE"/>
    </payloadData>
</streamDefinition>
<streamDefinition name="notificationStream" version="1.0.0">
<metaData>
        <property name="parameterId" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="slno" type="STRING"/>
</metaData>
    <payloadData>
        <property name="finalValue" type="INT"/>
        <property name="inputText" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="inputValue" type="DOUBLE"/>
    </payloadData>
</streamDefinition>
```

Comment: Thanx i will try it ..then let u know if i struck

Comment: I am not getting any events with above configuration i drop the 2 messages into jmsProxy but messages are unable move into cep I think error in Inputeventbuilder

Comment: how would it work my incoming message store in jmsProxy queue .my cep will pick the message form there and check the condition in given query expression then move to another jms but my Inputeventadaptor unable to pick the message from there

Comment: i am getting this message in CEP .. Event builder deployment held back and in inactive state :ReadingsDtoBuilder, Waiting for Input Event Adaptor dependency :jmsProxy

Comment: i am using activemq5.8.0 is it support for this version where as docs intiated about 5.7.0 only