# How to work with wso2CEP3.0.0 and activemq 5.8.0

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-esb

i am using wso2cep 3.0.0 and activemq5.8.0 
As per CEP documents i wish to Publish events using CEP.
For that i started activemq with 2 define **QUEUES** with the name **jmsProxy** for incoming message and **JmsProxy** for out message.I added required jars in CEP lib **activemq-broker-5.8.0.jar,activemq-client-5.8.0.jar,axiom.jar,geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar,geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar,hawtbuf-1.2.jar,xpp3-1.1.4c.jar,xstream-1.4.4.jar**

my configuration is like this
**InputEventAdaptor**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inputEventAdaptor name="jmsProxy" statistics="disable" trace="enable"
  type="jms" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventadaptormanager">
  <property name="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://localhost:61616</property>
  <property name="transport.jms.SubscriptionDurable">true</property>
  <property name="transport.jms.DurableSubscriberName">jmsProxy</property>
  <property name="transport.jms.UserName">admin</property>
  <property name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</property>
  <property name="transport.jms.Password">admin</property>
  <property name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName">QueueConnectionFactory</property>
  <property name="transport.jms.DestinationType">queue</property>
</inputEventAdaptor>
```

above for incoming messages which will pick the messages from **jmsProxy** queue
But its unable to pick the message from jmsProxy Queue.How would i initiate this to get the message into **CEP** and 
**outputEventAdaptor**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<outputEventAdaptor name="JmsProxy" statistics="disable" trace="disable"
  type="jms" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventadaptormanager">
  <property name="java.naming.security.principal">admin</property>
  <property name="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://localhost:61616</property>
  <property name="java.naming.security.credentials">admin</property>
  <property name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</property>
  <property name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName">QueueConnectionFactory</property>
  <property name="transport.jms.DestinationType">queue</property>
</outputEventAdaptor>
```

event builder configuration like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eventBuilder name="ReadingsDtoBuilder" statistics="disable"
    trace="disable" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventbuilder">
<from eventAdaptorName="jmsProxy" eventAdaptorType="jmsProxy">
    <property name="transport.jms.Destination">JmsProxy</property>
</from>
<mapping customMapping="disable"
    parentXpath="//ReadingsLiteTaildtos" type="xml">
    <property>
        <from xpath="//ReadingsLiteTaildto/ParameterId"/>
        <to name="meta_parameterId" type="string"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from xpath="//ReadingsLiteTaildto/Slno"/>
        <to name="meta_slno" type="string"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from xpath="//ReadingsLiteTaildto/FinalValue"/>
        <to name="finalValue" type="int"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from xpath="//ReadingsLiteTaildto/InputText"/>
        <to name="inputText" type="string"/>
    </property>
    <property>
        <from xpath="//ReadingsLiteTaildto/InputValue"/>
        <to name="inputValue" type="double"/>
    </property>
</mapping>
<to streamName="org.sample.readings.dto.stream" version="1.0.0"/>
</eventBuilder>
```

The execution plan can be as follows.like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<executionPlan name="ReadingsAnalyzer" statistics="disable"
  trace="disable" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventprocessor">
  <description>This execution plan analyzes readings and triggers notifications based on     threshold.</description>
  <siddhiConfiguration>
    <property name="siddhi.enable.distributed.processing">false</property>
    <property name="siddhi.persistence.snapshot.time.interval.minutes">0</property>
  </siddhiConfiguration>
  <importedStreams>
    <stream as="readings" name="org.sample.readings.dto.stream" version="1.0.0"/>
  </importedStreams>
  <queryExpressions><![CDATA[from readings[finalValue > 100]
select *
insert into notificationStream;]]></queryExpressions>
  <exportedStreams>
    <stream name="notificationStream" valueOf="notificationStream" version="1.0.0"/>
  </exportedStreams>
</executionPlan>
```

I defined streams inside stream-manager-config.xml similar to the following.

```
<streamDefinition name="org.sample.readings.dto.stream" version="1.0.0">
<metaData>
        <property name="parameterId" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="slno" type="STRING"/>
</metaData>
    <payloadData>
        <property name="finalValue" type="INT"/>
        <property name="inputText" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="inputValue" type="DOUBLE"/>
    </payloadData>
</streamDefinition>
<streamDefinition name="notificationStream" version="1.0.0">
<metaData>
        <property name="parameterId" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="slno" type="STRING"/>
</metaData>
    <payloadData>
        <property name="finalValue" type="INT"/>
        <property name="inputText" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="inputValue" type="DOUBLE"/>
    </payloadData>
</streamDefinition>.
```

its look like all well while i am sending any message to my jmsProxy queue the message is not reflecting to CEP for event and i am getting this message in **CEP**

```
[2014-02-18 11:57:53,159]  INFO - {EventBuilderDeployer}  Event Builder undeployed successfully : ReadingsDtoBuilder.xml
[2014-02-18 11:57:53,160]  INFO - {EventBuilderDeployer}  Event builder deployment held back and in inactive state :ReadingsDtoBuilder, Waiting for Input Event Adaptor dependency :jmsProxy
[2014-02-18 12:03:58,006]  INFO - {InputEventAdaptorConfigurationFilesystemInvoker}  Input Event Adaptor configuration deleted from file system : jmsProxy.xml
[2014-02-18 12:03:58,006]  INFO - {InputEventAdaptorDeployer}  Input Event Adaptor undeployed successfully : jmsProxy.xml
[2014-02-18 12:03:58,008]  INFO - {InputEventAdaptorConfigurationFilesystemInvoker}  Input Event Adaptor configuration saved in th filesystem : jmsProxy
[2014-02-18 12:03:58,009]  INFO - {InputEventAdaptorDeployer}  Input Event Adaptor deployed successfully and in active state : jmsProxy
[2014-02-18 12:03:58,009]  INFO - {EventBuilderDeployer}  Event Builder undeployed successfully : ReadingsDtoBuilder.xml
[2014-02-18 12:03:58,009]  INFO - {EventBuilderDeployer}  Event builder deployment held back and in inactive state :ReadingsDtoBuilder, Waiting for Input Event Adaptor dependency :jmsProxy
```

Comment: for more referance please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624344/how-event-stream-works-in-wso2cep3-0-0/21671482?noredirect=1#comment33067412_21671482

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your configuration, it seems that the event builder configuration is incorrect. Event adaptor type should be 'jms' in the event builder configuration.

```
<from eventAdaptorName="jmsProxy" eventAdaptorType="jms">
```

Please correct this as above to get it working. You can enable tracing [1] to see if messages come to a particular component of CEP.

[1] https://docs.wso2.org/display/CEP300/CEP+Event+Tracer